# UTF-16 in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a file.txt and content of it is:

> \u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f\u0020\u0057\u006f\u0072\u006c\u0064\u0021

It is 'Hello World!' in UTF-16.

If my code is:

```
let data = '\u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f\u0020\u0057\u006f\u0072\u006c\u0064\u0021';
console.log(data);
```

It is print out: 'Hello World!'

But If I use readFileSync() and console.log(), it isn't print out 'Hello World!':

```
let data = fs.readFileSync('file.txt',{encoding:'utf8', flag:'r'});
console.log(data);
```

Why?

Example:

[image: Example]

Comment: What about changing the encoding string to be `utf16`?

Comment: You have a utf16 file you read with utf8 encoding?

Comment: I mean: '\u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f\u0020\u0057\u006f\u0072\u006c\u0064\u0021' in normal text file

Answer (score 4):

In the source code of a JavaScript string literal, `\u` followed by four characters represents a position in the [Basic Multilingual Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane).

The same numbers, expressed in bytes, mean the same thing in various Unicode encodings.

Your text file **doesn't** contain bytes that represent those characters.

It contains bytes which represent the `\` character, the `u` character, etc.

Comment: So, what should i do to convert data read from file to utf8?

Comment: I'd store the data as text (as opposed to JS source code) in the first place.